# Output of svn log -v

Tags: svn

I just wonna know if the output of the command svn log -v is always the same. For me it looks like:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | username | 2011-01-16 16:52:23 +0100 (Sun, 16 Jan 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   D /foo
Removed foo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | balzarot | 2011-01-16 16:51:03 +0100 (Sun, 16 Jan 2011) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /foo
created foo
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I don't know if it is always like that, especially the format of the date!
Can you help me please
thnx

Answer (score 9):

If you're programmatically parsing the output of `svn` commands, you'll probably want to use the `--xml` switch:

```
svn log --xml
```

When using this format, the date (in particular) is in standard ISO 8601 format:

```
<date>2010-12-06T20:58:35.698893Z</date>
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, one of the goals of the text output from the SVN command line tools was that they be regular and machine parsable in addition to being human readable.  I just took a quick peek at the latest docs, and the format looks identical to what I remember reading about several years ago